# Setting Path for R interpreter in IntelliJ

Tags: r, intellij-idea

I want to use intelliJ for my R Scripts. When I am trying to run an R script, at first it was showing to Set the R interpreter with ntelliJ.

I have mentioned R.exe and then RScrpt.exe path from Settings->Langauge->R to 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Open\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe and then I am getting the following output when I am trying to run a code:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Open\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe" --no-save --quiet
  Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I'm resolving a similar output - with no details on the scripts I/O.  Also, when using the ggplot2 plugin, no plot is shown (theplot.draw()) yields the same output indicated by @Shankha Deep Karmakar.